# Tree layout algorithms in Ext JS and/or Processing.js

Tags: javascript, extjs, d3.js, processing.js

We need to display a tree using a "balloon layout" in our single-page web app.

The old version of our app creates the layout on the server (hand-coded) and then displays it on the client using Processing.js.

Our new application is built using Ext JS. Looking at what D3.js can do with layouts I would really like to do the layout on the client side but I don't think I can introduce a new JavaScript library into the project at this stage.

Is there graphical tree layout functionality in either Ext JS or Processing.js that would be similar to D3.js [Tree Layout](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Tree-Layout/)? Are there maybe extensions to Ext JS/Processing.js that can help?

Comment: ExtJs doesn't have such thing. With processing you would be able to do it but I don't think there is an out of the box solution.

Comment: as per A1rPun's comment, no such functionality is built into Processing. You'll have to either write it yourself, or just load whatever JS lets you do tree layours (D3 is a fine choice)

Comment: Thanks, looks like I'm doing D3.